# Import Apricity OS zsh theme into Manjaro

Tags: zsh, manjaro, theme

first post down here (and in my life) on a IT related forum

As you may have heard, Apricity OS (Arch linux based distro) just died officially last week. And for those who didn't knew this distro, it was beautiful and pretty cool to use (plenty of info on the prompt, VCS, multi line editing of code, exit codes, path, etc..).

[image: Typical look of Apricity's terminal]

Now that I've migrated to Manjaro (another Arch linux base distro) and I'm trying to retrieve the graphical elements of my old cherished distribution.

And after a few days trying to learn how Zsh and the prompt works, I'm wondering where those files can be stored on Apricity OS, so that I could just cp them into Manjaro and it would be ok, no ?

I've already tried oh-my-zsh, but i don't like it very much :/

So guys, can I just copy those files into my brand new Manjaro or is it kind of specific to Apricity ? And if so, have you any ideas of where those files (colors and infos of Apricity's prompt) can be stored ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that there is a package that can it, so I'm posting it here in case somebody is searching too :)

First install Powerline packages :

```
Pacman -S powerline powerline-vim powerline-fonts
```

Then in order to integrate it to ZSH, source powerline from ZSH bindings :

```
source /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh
```

And you are ready to go !